# Here maps with Angular: error when hiding UI controls

Tags: angular, typescript, here-api

I have a HERE map that I'm using in my Angular application. I have followed the doc [to set it up](https://developer.here.com/blog/display-here-maps-angular-web-application)

I want to hide some controls from the map, mainly the scalebar and the zoom control. However, I get a `setEnabled is not a function` error.

Here's my code:

```
public ngAfterViewInit() {
  const defaultLayers = this.platform.createDefaultLayers();
  if (this.mapElement) {
  this.map = new H.Map(
    this.mapElement.nativeElement,
    defaultLayers.normal.map,
    {
      zoom: 10
    });

    this.ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(this.map, defaultLayers, 'en-US');

    // This line throws a `setEnabled is not a function` error
    let scalebar = this.ui.getControl('scalebar').setEnabled(false);
  }
}
```

I'm doing [what's written in the doc](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics/map-controls.html) so I don't understand why this won't work. Any ideas?

**Additional Infos**: `this.ui.getControl('scalebar')` is not undefined. And I can see that the setEnabled method is not part of the prototype. (see screenshot)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can hide the scalebar with the following line of code:

```
this.ui.getControl('scalebar').setVisibility(false)
```

Side note:

I don't see any `setEnabled` method in the API reference, so this may be a typo in the documentation guide.

Source: **[H.ui.Control API reference](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics_api/h-ui-control.html#h-ui-control)**

Comment: Thank you so much! HERE should update their doc... I was following this page: https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics/map-controls.html

Answer (score 2):

If you have the line:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-ui.css" />
```

in the head section of your code, comment it. 
You will not see the scale bar and zoom control on the map.
This line is responsible for the default UI controls on the map.

Comment: Just tried it, but it breaks the map (I get weird black and grey artifacts) so it's a no go. Any idea with the 'setEnabled' doesn't work? I tried setAlignment('top-left') for fun and this one does work...